# Cannot find winemenubuilder.exe when trying to run StarCraft 2

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

Recently I've installed StarCraft 2 via playonlinux. The installation was absolutly no problem, everything was fine. But if I want to start the game now, it crashes.
If I start it on the Terminal I get following error:

```
optirun /usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "StarCraft II Wings of Liberty"
[POL_Wine_SetVersionEnv] Message: Setting wine version path: 1.3.27, amd64
[POL_Wine_SetVersionEnv] Message: "/home/gernot/.PlayOnLinux//wine/linux-amd64/1.3.27" exists
[POL_Wine] Message: Running wine-1.3.27 StarCraft II.exe
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe"
rm: Cannot remove »*“ : Can't find directory or file.
```

Has anybody an idea what to do?

Comment: If I run the starcraft.exe directly with wine the Downloader for the Updates is working. Eventually also the game itself... . Does somebody know why it isn't working with POL?

Comment: Bad news, the game isn't working... If I just run it with wine/pol I get the error, that DirectX could not be initialized. If I run it with optirun, I get this message:
[VGL] ERROR: Could not open display :8.
What can I do, to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Starcraft2 is one of the program affected by the Ubuntu 12.04 kernel bug.
here is my answer to the same problem with another program

[Problem with Wine on Kernel 3.2.0](https://askubuntu.com/a/141925/65969)

I also found this:

> If the problem persists, remove your folder "home/documents/starcraft II" 
>   Problems may remain on highest graphics setting.

[ON this page about half way down](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=4619;tips=1)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunatlly none of these hints solved the problem. I still get the message that directx can not be initialized...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. You can install DirectX via winetricks but I'm unsure how to do it.. I think I read somewhere that it will break WINE if you don't do it right. I use Crossover's WINE so the install for DirectX for me just involves selecting the option and clicking install.  However most programs that work with Crossover work with the free WINE.  You might try searching for DiretX on www.winehq.org it brings up pages of articles.  If you ask the same question on their forums as here you might get better results.  Wish I could be of more help.